# How feasible is it to grow algae on Mars to use as food, plastic and oxygen production?

Tags: materials, oxygen, food

I am currently researching the idea of growing spirulina algae on Mars for as a renewable source of oxygen, food and material. So the question arises: How feasible would it be to grow spirulina in an artificial habitat on Mars?

Comment: I'd link up your sources from your answer on uhoh's question, gives context: https://www.sanat.co.in/health-blog/123/why-nasa-has-recommends-spirulina-as-excellent-space-food and http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1516-89132016000100409

Comment: Growing algae on the surface of Mars and within its atmosphere, or growing them in greenhouses on Mars with a different atmosphere?

Comment: @Uwe Edit: Clarified question, should have done this earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[There are photosynthesizing organisms](https://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/20120515-earth-life-survive-mars.html) capable of growing on Mars !**
Some places on Mars near the equator are low enough to have liquid water on the surface for a few hours.

But as @anon  stated in [his answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30249/how-feasible-is-it-to-grow-algae-on-mars-to-use-as-food-plastic-and-oxygen-prod/30253#30253) there are other oxygen producing organisms that are better suited  for use as food or the production of plastic than [algae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algae).

Could one of them be **[Nostoc Commune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostoc_commune)** ?

[image]

Photo taken by YAMAMAYA

[Nostoc Commune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostoc_commune) is a species of [cyanobacterium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanobacteria), so it produces oxygen, common names include star jelly and fah-tsai. It's a colonial species, forming a gelatinous mass with other colonies growing nearby and between the ordinary cells **nitrogen-fixing** cells occur.
It is found in many countries around the world and is able to survive in **extreme conditions** in polar regions and **arid** areas. The cells also contain pigments that absorb ultraviolet radiation which enables it **to survive in places where high levels of radiation occur !**

It produces extracellular  polysaccharides  that can be used for plastic production.

Nostoc Commune is [eaten in east Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostoc_commune#Uses).

I think [algae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algae) are not suitable for Mars, in particular because of the dry conditions there and the ultraviolet radiation, but it well may be that Nostoc Cummune is suitable within the lower regions near the equator !

Comment: I like this post simply for the new microbes people bring to it. This is indeed an awesome species because it is nitrogen fixing and edible. The hardest part with plants is meeting their nutritional demands which in a world like ours is usually handled by a plethora of other microbes that compose their ecosystem. Anyways, mars's atmosphere is nitrogen starved and the equatorial nights go well below freezing, even these would not be able to survive unprotected.

Comment: @anon  You could be right, i only know that it's able to survive in extreme conditions in polar regions. Regarding nitrogen, there is some in Mars's atmosphere and when not enough then we have to choose the regions where there are nitrates in the rocks or soils.

Comment: to my knowledge nitrates dont occur naturally(geologically). They are created by organisms like the one above and then just recycled endlessly. A sterile world like Mars shouldnt have natural nitrates.

Comment: @anon  Look for nitrate and Mars and you will find that Curiosity found nitrate in windblown sediments.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few questions like this but I cant find one that addresses all the avenues of this question.

1) No known terrestrial photosynthesizing organism is capable of growing on Mars currently. This is because of the temperature and pressure of Mars as well as the fact that it's very dry. These aspects are important because, as far we know it, all photosynthesizing life forms require liquid water which would either freeze or vaporize on Mars. Thus seeding Mars with algae would do nothing.

2) If you meant raising algae in controlled environments on Mars that's a little different. It is possible but not necessarily feasible.

- Algae does not make for good human food.
- Algae requires a lot more water to productively grow than other plants.
- Algae harvesting and processing requires more equipment than other plants
- there are methods that can produce plastics from processing any organic matter

In short, there is a long list of plants better suited for these purposes than algae.

Comment: "terrestrial photosynthesizing organism" - This phrase is ambiguous. It is used to refer to photosynthesizing organisms that grow on land, and it could also mean photosynthesizing organisms on Earth. I suspect you mean the latter, but you should probably clarify.

Comment: These two points are most pertinent to the OP's question and could use some further detail and sources: "Algae requires a lot more water to productively grow than other plants." "Algae harvesting and processing requires more equipment than other plants"

Comment: Can you give me specific list of plants?

Comment: @Awesomepotato29 lol ok, http://www.fao.org/fileadmin/templates/ess/documents/world_census_of_agriculture/appendix4_r7.pdf

Comment: @anon actually... [Algae ARE good food](https://www.sanat.co.in/health-blog/123/why-nasa-has-recommends-spirulina-as-excellent-space-food)

Comment: @called2voyage yes a lot more detail could be done on farming, harvesting, and processing techniques of algae. That however is a whole world of information beyond this question and stack. But plain and simple, to effectively grow algae you need an aquatic environment which instantly makes it as water demanding as rice.  Then obviously to separate it from the water you need a filter, I dont need a filter to harvest rice.

Comment: Hold on I didnt know about this spirulina variant, my answer applies to the majority of algae which is where it is true. This stuff is interesting but the water requirements still pose an issue, need to look at this more.

Comment: A definite problem with spirulina is that you need to supply its nutrients only and not any toxins. Any toxins present or organisms that manage those toxins will end up in the edible product. It is not impossible it just requires research and engineering.

Comment: @anon I was hoping for an actual list, not just a literal list of every substance cultivated for profit by man. "Tobacco-only colony on Mars is always coughing for some reason-- 'I'd rather *cough* eat algae *cough*.' one man was quoted saying." I mean even the plant used to make mace is on that list haha.

Comment: The point at the time I was trying to make was that just about every other edible plant had value over algae because i didnt know about this spirulina variant. Algae is actually an incredibly large group of organisms most of which are not fit for human consumption.

Comment: @anon Sorry, I should have clarified.